# bitbucket pipelines dual caching not working

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

Hey i`ve a problem with my bitbucket pipeline caching.

I see in first step, that the caching is working like that:

```
Cache "cpphp71": Downloading
Cache "cpphp71": Downloaded 3 MB in 4 seconds
Cache "cpphp71": Extracting
Cache "cpphp71": Extracted in 0 seconds
```

But when it's uploading the cache again this message is displayed:

```
Cache "cpphp71": Skipping upload for existing cache
```

I don't really know what to change so it's working again.

```
image: albertcolom/ci-pipeline-php:7.1-alpine

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: testing
        caches:
          - cpphp71
        script:
          - php --version
    - step:
        name: Package build
        caches:
          - cpphp71
        script:
          - echo "test"
definitions:
  caches:
    cpphp71: /test/.rl/repo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cache only uploads if no cache exits. The cache automatically clears itself after a week. You can also clear in via the bitbucket UI. 
If you have two different dependencies you should create two caches like this.

```
image: albertcolom/ci-pipeline-php:7.1-alpine

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: testing
        caches:
          - cpphp71_1
        script:
          - php --version
    - step:
        name: Package build
        caches:
          - cpphp71_2
        script:
          - echo "test"
definitions:
  caches:
    cpphp71_1: /test/.rl/repo
    cpphp71_2: /test/.rl/repo
```

For more information about caching see here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/caching-dependencies-895552876.html